# How to change max server memory in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I was trying to change the max server memory for my database server, and I accidentally saved it as "4" instead of the number I wanted to enter.

Now I can't even connect to the server.

Is there a way for me to reset the max server memory setting to the default value without connecting to the database server somehow?

Answer (score 7):

Just start SQL Server with the -f switch, which will start it in a minimal, single-user mode. You should be able to change it back afterwards.

Comment: I'm very beginner when it comes to this stuff. Can you give me a link that will show me how to do that?

Comment: You should be able to start it with a simple "sqlservr.exe -f" in the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to start sql server in single user mode and set max server memory by using following command.

1.http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/10/sql-server-start-sql-server-instance-in-single-user-mode/

2.sp_configure 'Max Server Memory',**1024**
  reconfigure

When you are starting sql server in single user mode you have to disconnect all connections.